# Java: Can't understand how newInstance() and getSuperClass() ,methods of Class class are working

Tags: java

Here is example from "Java Philosophy" book (remember that FancyToy extends Toy):

```
Class<FancyToy> ftClass = FancyToy.class;
Class<? super FancyToy> up = ftClass.getSuperclass(); //compiles
Class<Toy> up = ftClass.getSuperclass(); //doesn't compile
```

Tried it in IDEA a lot of times, just have an "Incompatible types" message. Please, give me a hint, why we can't use generic type **Toy** only?

Thank you

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: A suprising accept, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct superclass of FancyToy might be another class!

Your second line says that: it should be *some* class that FancyToy extends.

Whereas your third line says exactly which class is required. And either there is actually a level between Toy and FancyToy, or the compiler doesn't do the necessary type inference here.